# Numpy array gets filpped from column to row vector

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays a1 and q_u. When I try matmul on them, it does not work for some reason.
As far as I understand it, q_u gets flipped (at least when I print q_u[:,i], it gives me a line and not a column vector.

How would I fix this?

```
a1= 
 [[1. 0. 0.]
 [ 0. 1. 0.]
 [ 0. 0. 1.]]

q_u= 
 [[-0.1752437 ]
 [ 0.85065081]
 [-0.1752437 ]]

P_hat = np.matmul(a1,q_u[:,i])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-580d1a258ebe> in <module>
    156 
    157 for i in range(len(time)-1):
--> 158     P_hat = np.matmul(a1,q_u[:,i])

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 1 is different from 3)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just `q_u`?

Comment: It does not "flip". A 1d array is represented in a row. Whether you're taking a row or a column from a 2d array, the slice is a 1d array so it's represented like that. But internally numpy will take care of things for you. Having said that, are your arrays representative of what's going on? `q_u` has shape (3, 1), so `q_u[:,1]` is out of bounds. `np.matmul(a1, q_u[:,0])` works fine for me. Your error implies a mismatch in dimensions, as if you were to do `np.matmul(a1, q_u[:-1,0])` given your current values.

Comment: @diggusbickus  I need to repeat the multiplication for N timesteps, which is the reason for the for loop. (I have not posted the entire code here, only a snippet).

Comment: `a1` is (3,1).  So is `q_u`.  `q_u[:,0]` is (3,) (standard indexing by a scalar).  What `matmul` do you want?  Do you understand what `matmul` does with various dimension combinations?  Don't make assumptions.